# How to call python script from c++ (Clion)

Tags: python, c++, excel, pywin32, win32com

OK, so after searching a little too hard over the internet I still have my same issue. I have a very simple python script that opens up the specified excel file and then runs a macro.

I know for a fact that my python script runs as it should stand alone.
I know for a fact that my C++ code runs as it should.

But the combo of both creates a 'com_error'. Just so anyone who sees this knows, these are all the tests I have ran:

(1) simple python script (just prints hello) --> passed
(2) use C++ to run same simple .py script --> passed
(3) more advanecd python script (opens excel, runs macro, save and close) --> pass
(4) usc C++ code to run advanced .py script --> fail.

And there is my problem. this has something to do with the win32com.client and an error the server throws because it cant find the file location (but trust me it can because it passed the 'find file' test)

I'm running Windows7, Python 2.7, And the latest version of JetBrains Clion (2017.1.2).

Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks! Happy coding.

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *cmd = "python C:\\Users\\Alex.Valente\\Desktop\\python.py";

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo                = {0};
    startupInfo.cb                         = sizeof(startupInfo);




    BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)cmd,
                                NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                                GetEnvironmentStrings(), NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    if(!result){
        return -1;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );
    return 0;
}
```

Python Script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client
import os

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = r'C:\Users\Alex.Valente\Desktop\Data.csv'
            xlApp.Visible = True
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!PythonTest")
            wb.Save()
            wb.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And the Error that is printed after I run it:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_excel_macro (__main__.ExcelMacro)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex.Valente\Desktop\python.py", line 25, in test_excel_macro
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server threw an exception.', None, None)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 6.305s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the python script via bat or PowerShell script? These are especially good for simple tasks, like when you just need to run something.
Also, Clion is an IDE and has nothing to do with the issue. It may be helpful if you would specify the compiler, though.

Comment: the only reason I included the IDE is because a lot of the time when you code in an IDE it creates an virtual environment and sometimes for whatever reason that can give permission errors. It can be the cause of problems and im thinking that what it is. They python is using the win23com.client and because Clion is technically running the code in its environment, and it cant access the library properly and is pooping its pants. That's why I include " GetEnvironmentStrings()" in my CreateProssess call. But still didn't work. I might try doing this via a bat script. thanks for the idea!